# передача json в переменную с помощью axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

Нужно получить с сервера json-файл и записать эти данные в переменную.

```
        axios.get(url).then(
        promise => console.log(promise.data)
        )
```

Таким образом в консоль выводится то, что нужно, но как записать эти данные в переменную?

Comment: promise => { var a = promise.data }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
axios.get(url).then(
  response => {
    var a = response.data
  }
)
```