# Как вызвать action и вернуть getters во Vuex

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

**Задача**: получить данные из JSON в хранилище Vuex и присвоить их переменной.

---

Данные я получаю через Axios:

```
loadGameData ({commit}) {   
  axios.get('table_json/game-data.json').then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);           
  }); 
}
```

Данные успешно получены и выводятся в консоли. Но мне нужно, чтобы содержимое JSON записывалось в переменную. Нашла [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819228/), однако предложенные там решения у меня не сработали.

```
// Пробовала так:
loadGameData ({commit}) {   
  axios.get('table_json/game-data.json').then(response => {
    var a = response.data;
  });

  console.log(a);
}

// ... и так:
loadGameData ({commit}) {  
  axios.get('table_json/game-data.json').then (promise => {
    var a = promise.data;
  });

  console.log(a);
}
```

Не работает – в обоих случаях в консоли ошибка:

> ReferenceError: 'a' is not defined.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу.

Comment: @Рустам, сейчас у меня мутации прописаны так:    mutations: {
    getGame(state, games) {
      state.games = games
    },   
   
  }  Поясните, пожалуйста, что значит "пробрасывать" и как конкретно это реализовать? Документацию Vuex я, разумеется, читала, но это не помогло найти решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобные вопросы уже задавались много раз. Если коротко и в упрощенной формулировке:

- в компоненте вызывается метод (action) в хранилище;
- этот метод выполняет асинхронный запрос (axios);
- результаты запроса пробрасываются (передаются) в мутации (mutations);
- в мутациях меняется состояние (state) хранилища;
- в компоненте через вычисляемое (computed) свойство происходит обновление данных.

Демо с небольшими комментариями:

```js
// Список доступных мутаций (сеттеры).
const SET_COLLECTION = 'SET_COLLECTION';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // STATE - изначальное состояние.
  state: {
    collection: [],
  },

  // GET - получить, достать.
  getters: {
    // Вернуть все записи.
    all: state => state.collection,

    // Вернуть запись по `id`.
    byId: state => id => state.collection.find(article => id === article.id),

    // Вернуть записи,
    // поле `field` у которых равен `val`.
    where: state => (field, val) => state.collection.filter(article => val == article[field]),

    // Вернуть записи, поле `field` у которых
    // равен одному из значений `values`.
    // Приведу полную запись, без сокращений.
    whereIn: function whereIn(state) {
      return function(field, values) {
        return state.collection.filter(function(article) {
          return values.includes(article[field]);
        });
      }
    },
  },

  // SET - установить, задать.
  // Обработчики мутаций обязаны быть синхронными.
  // Все мутации - это сеттеры.
  mutations: {
    [SET_COLLECTION](state, collection) {
      state.collection = collection;
    },
  },

  // ACTION - действие.
  // Асинхронные запросы всегда помещаются в `action`.
  // Но НЕ все действия обязаны быть асинхронными.
  actions: {
    load(context) {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(function(response) {
          // Полученные результаты запроса отправляются в `mutations`.
          context.commit('SET_COLLECTION', response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);

          context.commit('SET_COLLECTION', []);
        });
    }

    // // Либо вариант с `async/await`.
    // async load(context) {
    //     try {
    //         const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    //
    //         context.commit('SET_COLLECTION', response.data);
    //     } catch (error) {
    //         console.log(error);
    //
    //         context.commit('SET_COLLECTION', []);
    //     }
    // }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    checked: [8]
  },

  computed: {
    // При компонентном подходе ...mapGetters().
    // Теперь в компоненте доступно свойство `articles`,
    // которое будет автоматически обновляться
    // при изменениях, внесенными мутациями.
    ...Vuex.mapGetters({
      articles: 'all',
      whereIn: 'whereIn'
    }),

    ids() {
      return this.articles.map(article => article.id);
    },

    // Пример, когда в хранилище передается параметр.
    // Подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982247/256824.
    filtered() {
      return this.whereIn('id', this.checked)
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.load();
  },

  methods: {
    // При компонентном подходе ...mapActions().
    // Теперь в компоненте доступен метод: this.load().
    ...Vuex.mapActions([
      'load'
    ]),
  }
});
```

```css
.filter {
  max-height: 188px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filter-label {
  display: block;
}

.articles {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.article {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article-title {
  color: #08c;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h4>Выбранные идентификаторы записей {{ checked }}</h4>

  <div class="articles">
    <div class="filter">
      <label v-for="id in ids" class="filter-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" :value="id" /> {{ id }}
                </label>
    </div>

    <article class="article" v-for="(article, index) in filtered">
      <h3 class="article-title">{{ article.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Обновлено**
Добавлен пример фильтрации.

Answer (score 0):

```
loadGameData ({commit}) {   
   axios.get('table_json/game-data.json').then(
       response => { var a = response.data }
   );
   console.log(a)
}
```

[Асинхронность в JavaScript: Пособие для тех, кто хочет разобраться](https://habr.com/en/company/wrike/blog/302896/)

В вашем коде `console.log(a)` выполняется раньше чем приходит ответ в axios, по этому и undefined. 
Вам нужно внутри `then` выполнить мутацию, чтобы поменять состояние модели. Проще говоря

```
axios.get('table_json/game-data.json').then(
   response => {
                var a = response.data;
                //Именно тут доступны ваши данные и тут вы можете использовать мутацию
               }
);  

// А тут a на момент выполнения недоступно и это логично, т.к. этот код выполняется раньше нежели промис меняет статус.

console.log(a);
```