# Вывод данных для списка из массива данных с помощью vuex (store.js)

Tags: vue.js

Есть небольшой vue проект [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-lp-2-pqcm0?fontsize=14)

Была создана бд в firebase откуда тяну данные для вывода списка **product**

**firebase:**

```
const config = {
  ...
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

// firebase utils
const db = firebase.firestore();

// firebase collections
const usersCollection = db.collection("users");
const locationsCollection = db.collection("locations");

export { firebase, db, usersCollection, locationsCollection };
```

**store.js:**

```
import { firebase, locationsCollection } from "@/firebase";

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    appTitle: "Landing Page",
    locations: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setLocations(state, payload) {
      state.locations = payload;
    },
    setUserLocations(state, payload) {
      state.userLocations = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getLocations({ state, commit }) {
      locationsCollection
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          let locationsArray = [];

          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let location = doc.data();
            location.id = doc.id;
            locationsArray.push(location);
          });

          commit("setLocations", locationsArray);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          commit("setLocations", []);
        });
    },
    addLocation({ state }, payload) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child("/locations")
        .push(payload);

      //console.log(payload);
    },
    getUserLocations({ state, commit }) {
      return firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/locations")
        .once("value", snapshot => {
          commit("setUserLocations", snapshot.val());
        });
    }
  },
  getters: {}
});
```

**Вопрос:** В проекте есть файл **data.json**. Как можно аналогичным способом , только не с firebase, а с json файла или просто с массива "стянуть" данные для **product** ?

P.S: [Вопрос не решает мою проблему и не связан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013794/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-action-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-getters-%D0%B2%D0%BE-vuex)

Comment: Для этого необходим сервер, настроенный на обработку таких запросов.  А так - Вы, можете,  подключить его к странице или к компоненту, как обычный   js-файл.

Comment: @Дмытрык, а если просто как файлик, через store можно как-то "управлять" ?)

Comment: Ну, да. Импортируете его в store и делаете с ним, что хотите. Только при таком подходе, файл попадет в бандл. Возможно, можно подключить его динамически, как и компоненты, но надо пробовать

Comment: @Дмытрык, в том-то и вопрос как в store с ним делать все что хочется)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вызвать action и вернуть getters во Vuex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013794/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-action-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-getters-%d0%b2%d0%be-vuex)

Comment: Какое имеет значение где вы храните информацию - `firebase`, файл `*.json`, массив объектов, LocalStorage - принцип работы хранилища Vuex от этого не меняется.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, еще раз повторюсь, вопрос не связан и ответы в том вопросе мне не помогли!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: 
`store.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
//import axios from "axios";
import { firebase, locationsCollection } from "@/firebase";
import  data  from "./data.json";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    appTitle: "Landing Page",
    locations: getLocations(data.locations)
  },
  mutations: {
    // setLocations(state, payload) {
    //   state.locations = payload;
    // },
    setUserLocations(state, payload) {
      state.userLocations = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async getLocations({ state, commit }) {
      // locationsCollection
      //   .get()
      //   .then(querySnapshot => {
      //     let locationsArray = [];
      //     querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      //       let location = doc.data();
      //       location.id = doc.id;
      //       locationsArray.push(location);
      //     });
      //     commit("setLocations", locationsArray);
      //   })
      //   .catch(() => {
      //     commit("setLocations", []);
      //   });
    },
    addLocation({ state }, payload) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child("/locations")
        .push(payload);

      //console.log(payload);
    },
    getUserLocations({ state, commit }) {
      return firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/locations")
        .once("value", snapshot => {
          commit("setUserLocations", snapshot.val());
        });
    }
  },
  getters: {}
});

function getLocations(data) {
  let locationsArray = [];
  data.forEach((doc, index) => {
    let location = doc.location;
    location.id = index;
    locationsArray.push(location);
  });
  return locationsArray;
}
```

При такой постановке задачи, Вам, ни mutations, ни actions - не нужны. Все сформируется при инициализации. Показал на примере получения locations.  Что делает `getUserLocations` - я не понял. Перепишите его логику сами.

Comment: Можно глупый вопрос, action\mutation в основном нужны при запросах к бд (api), но если что-то статическое (готовый массив или json файл внутри проекта) , то просто обработка массива и это из-за асинхронных действий?

Comment: Никак не могу понять action mutation )

Comment: Actions нужны для асинхронных действий (запросы к бд). Мутации нужны, чтобы из любого места приложения можно было как изменить хранилище, так и отследить его изменение. В Вашем случае, actions отпадают сразу, т.к. запросы к БД делать не надо. Мутации под вопросом. Однако, если они созданы только для того, чтобы изменить состояние после единственного запроса к БД, то и они отпадают. Таково мое виденье.

Comment: А если, доступ к данным у Вас осуществляется только в одном компоненте. И Вы их никак не планируете изменять и следить за этими изменениями, то смысла во Vuex нет тоже.  Vuex нужен, только если Вам необходимо динамически менять данные + следить за этими изменениями из разных точек приложения. Метод `addLocation` можно перенести в обычный mixin.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!